# Fullcalendar: How Do I fit the calendar to the size of screen

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to fit the `fullcalendar` to the size of screen. I tried using `css` styling but it is making it is not dynamic. Any other way where the size of `fullcalendar` will `resize` itself when user zooms in/out or the zoom % has no effect on `fullcalendar` size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Solved it.
```

[I have referred to this link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/aspectRatio)
and did `Hit & Try method`. With following code, the `fullcalendar` resizes itself to fit within the size of the `screen`. There is no overflow. At least works on Google Chrome.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    aspectRatio:  3 
});
```

Comment: Doing this now results in a Calendar that is 1/2 the current screen size.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    //resize just happened, pixels changed
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'height', window.innerHeight);
});
```

This works for me